# how to add a virtual directory to an angular 8 website hosted in IIS

Tags: angular, iis, hosting, angular8

I have managed to deploy an angular application in IIS,
 I have also added the a virtual directory which contains images to the site.
[Photo from IIS showing contents of the virtual directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esSAK.png) Images

When I load the website. Images don't show they return error 500 as show in the screen shot below. 
[Developer console image show error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8omm.png)

How can I confiture IIS and URL Rewrite to load the images in the website.

HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error. 
Above is the returned error when you try to load the image address in the new tab.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You need to review the actual IIS error page from Network tab in developer tools of the browser. That error page contains much more information about the problem. Besides, learn FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Hello @LexLi Am using Chrome, how do I access the IIS Error page, in dev tools I see no such option. Thanks very much.

Comment: Please learn the tools carefully so that you don't miss such https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network#search

Comment: To troubleshooting 500 error, you may need to enable real error and access the URL directly. For 500.50,you'd better create a Failed request tracing rule for 500.50 and check what's the detailed error message.